# Unable to play the video, could only hear it

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, codec

There is an interesting thing happening! When I try to play a video like :

```
<div class='vcontainer' id='vc'> 
        <video id="match" width="700" controls>
              <source src='tsk1.mp4' type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
</div>
```

I could only hear it and there is no video. It has a frame height of `576` and frame width of `720`. But I am able to play another video (normally), with a frame height of `320` and frame width of `568`. What could be the reason for this?

*Note:For reference I have also [uploaded the video file](https://vid.me/tYkv) that is causing an issue*

Comment: I'm sure the codec you encoded the video with isn't supported.  What codec and platform?

Comment: @Brad but it plays when uploaded on the link I shared. (See edit)

Comment: Sure, you uploaded it to a service that probably transcoded the video.  What codec and platform?

Comment: @Brad It is a `.mp4` file recorded from a TV Tuner software.

Comment: MP4 is the container... what's the codec?

Comment: Can you create fiddle for it?

Comment: @Brad I am not sure about the codec. But is there a way, I could make the browser decode the audio-video file?

Comment: Have you check your video in browser. even it's not playing in browser display just blank screen. Check http://i.stack.imgur.com/NAiLR.png.  Brad is right your video have codec issue i think.

Comment: Seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/6uk02ftf/1/

Comment: @SuhailGupta Yes... use a codec that is supported.

Comment: @Brad I found the codec : http://s13.postimg.org/e7jgrbnxz/Capture.jpg

Comment: @Brad I checked that the codec for the video is [mpeg4](http://s13.postimg.org/e7jgrbnxz/Capture.jpg) which is supported by chrome for .mp4 : https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183093?hl=en Shouldn't it play the video normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your video is probably in unsupported **codec** as said in the comment.
By saying codec, it's not the container format (mp4).

A container format is a format that combines several tracks (audio or video) along with some extra information (such as metadata) into one file or stream.

Currently most browsers support videos with mp4 format using baseline H.264 as image codec and arc/mp3 as audio codec.

Check if your video codec is H.264. Your browser can play sound proves that you got the right codec for audio, but maybe you're using some unsupported video codec.

Even if your video is H.264, you may still encounter problems. AFAIK, Chrome supports only yuv420p pixel format, while safari can also support yuvj420p. The version of H.264 may also cause problem, use baseline will be a good choice.

Your only way to make the video work is to transcode it to browser compatible format (Most video hosting websites will do this for you). You can do this with [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) using the command below.

`ffmpeg -i <Your video path here> -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -pix_format yuv420p -profile:v baseline -preset:v fast <Output video path here>`

Comment: Is there a way I could play it, like the service I uploaded to, is able to play the video

Comment: I checked that the codec for the video is [mpeg4](http://s13.postimg.org/e7jgrbnxz/Capture.jpg) which is supported by chrome for .mp4 : https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183093?hl=en Shouldn't it play the video normally?

Comment: @SuhailGupta, just as I said before, using a supported codec may not fix things. The used pixel format and many other things may also cause compatibility problems. First you should use a playable video url (there is one in the comment of your question) to checkout if it's something in your css that caused your `video` to be invisible. If the video is still invisible, then just try my way using FFmpeg.

Comment: @SuhailGupta, BTW, the image you posted is over-shrinked, can't see a thing.

Comment: I manually converted the video to H.264 and it plays normally.

Comment: Also, I uploaded the magnified version of the image : http://s17.postimg.org/ewut73e33/Capture.jpg

Comment: @SuhailGupta, still over shrinked, did you select a proper scale?

Comment: It displays the codec as : `taglib.mpeg4.isoaudiosampleentry`

Comment: I searched out that chrome had a bug with video (play audio with black image) and was fixed just recently.

Comment: @SuhailGupta They say they solved the issue, but I'm not sure whether the patch is included in the latest stable release.